# Java interface's method that uses another interface type

Tags: java, interface

I have a method in my interface (A) that accepts another interface (B) as a parameter. When I go to implement (A) and pass an object (C) that implements interface (B), I am stuck downcasting (B) to the right implementation (C) of the passed object.

For example...

```
public interface A {
    public void theMethod(B theObject);
}

public interface B {
    public Properties jarJar();

    public boolean isActuallyAJedi();

    public void srsly();
}

public class C implements B {
    //mumbo dumbo stuff from B
}

public class D implements A {
    public void theMethod(B theObject) { // <------ I would prefer to explicitly define C as it is implementing B
        C theUpcastedObject = (C) theObject; // <------ I want to avoid downcast here

        theUpcastedObject.isActuallyAJedi();

        theObject.srsly(); // <----- won't work because it is not aware of the implementation...
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        D stuffIWillDo = new D();
        B theObject = new C(); // explicitly showing the implementation here...

        D.theMethod(theObject);

    }
}
```

I hope this explains this well!

Comment: Note that that's a downcast, not an upcast.  But it sounds like you want generics.

Comment: You can't avoid downcasting, because any person who uses your class C using interface A would think any object of class B can be passed to this method. As mentioned above you can use generics instead if they fit your use case.

Comment: like @OliverCharlesworth said, sounds like generics to me

Comment: Why do you want to downcast unless you want to invoke methods specific to C ?

Comment: I don't think you need casting, by the way it is down-casting, in this case because C must implements methods being had by B. So, when you pass theObject to theMethod, and without declaring new reference i.e. theUpcastedObject, you can use it directly.

Comment: I was trying to avoid (don't ask why) generics but I will just roll with it anyway. Thank you all

Comment: There is no need for generics here. As @snr explained you only use methods declared in interface B. So there is no reason that your method have to know the exact implementation type. And your comment about `theObject.srsly()` is incorrect. This method is declared in interface B so you can call it.

Answer (score -1):

The class `C` which implements the interface `B` doesn't override the methods of interface `B`. I guess what you are trying to do here is extending the interface `B`. But a class can't extend an interface. What you can do here is make `C` an interface which will extend interface `B`.